# Add prefix to every single hostname in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I have a string like: `a.com b.com c.com`

How can I add to the front of it to make it like `*.a.com *.b.com *.c.com` using Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we have a file named `testfile` with the following content:

```
a.com b.com c.com
```

You can use:

```
sed -i 's/^/\*./g;s/ / *./g' testfile
```

If you like to use it in shell directly:

```
echo "a.com b.com c.com" | sed 's/^/\*./g;s/ / *./g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are on separate lines, you can do this with a one-liner:

```
awk '{print "*." $0}' < infile > outfile
```

If these are all on a single line, use:

```
cat infile | sed 's/ /\n/g' | awk '{print "*." $0}' > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
echo "a.com" | sed 's/^/*./'
```

Output:

```
*.a.com
```